# how can convert persian datettime to DateTime with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have one texbox in form that user insert persian DateTime
i want convert persian date to Datetime for Save in sql
thanx for answers

Comment: Have you looked at using the DateTime.ParseExact() method?

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of articles on CodeProject you might find useful:

[Persian DateTime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PersianDateTime.aspx)
[Farsi Library - Working with Dates, Calendars, and DatePickers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/FarsiLibrary.aspx)

Search CodeProject for "Persian" and I bet you'll find a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) with a Persian [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx):

```
var input = "8/30/2009 03:32";
var datetime = DateTime.Parse(input, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR"));
```

Comment: thanx but i convert from Persian DateTime  to Date Time
that is Convert Datetime to Persian DateTime

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code :

```
using System.Globalization;

PersianCalendar pCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
int year = pCalendar.GetYear(a);
int month = pCalendar.GetMonth(a);
int day = pCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(a);
int hour = pCalendar.GetHour(a);
int min = pCalendar.GetMinute(a);
int sec = pCalendar.GetSecond(a);
int mSec = int.Parse(pCalendar.GetMilliseconds(a).ToString());

MessageBox.Show(year + "/" + month + "/" + day);// persian date
DateTime dateTime = pCalendar.ToDateTime(year,month,day,hour,min,sec,mSec);
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToShortDateString());//DateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pCalendar = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
int year = pCalendar.GetYear(MiladyDateTime);
int month = pCalendar.GetMonth(MiladyDateTime);
int day = pCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(MiladyDateTime);
int hour = pCalendar.GetHour(MiladyDateTime);
int min = pCalendar.GetMinute(MiladyDateTime);
int sec = pCalendar.GetSecond(MiladyDateTime);
int mSec = int.Parse(pCalendar.GetMilliseconds(MiladyDateTime).ToString());
int era = pCalendar.GetEra(MiladyDateTime);
string Date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, mSec).ToString();
```